# I need a problem with a system of 100 equations to solve Numerically

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I need a problem with 100 equations , it doesn't matter if it's linear or non-linear , if you can provide me with both I'd be really grateful, I hope this question gets answered within two days , the faster the better.

Note : I've been searching google for hours with no luck , that's why I need an expert that experienced a problem with 100 equations to solve .

Note : I'm not asking for the solution , I'm asking for the problem to solve.

note : I need a real life problem not make one myself.

Comment: not a question ---------------

Comment: For $1\le n\le 99$ have $a_n+a_{n+1}=n^2$ and $a_{100}+a_1=10000$ - it is easy to make up a hundred equations, your question really doesn't ask for anything clear. So I don't know whether this set would be an adequate answer or not - so I'm voting to close because the question is unclear.

Comment: Why not just make one up?  Make a $100 \times 100$ array of random numbers for the coefficients of a set of linear equations and a vector of $100$ random numbers for the constants.

Comment: I'm sorry if I broke a rule, I should've said I need a real problem not make up one . whether it was a mathematical or engineering related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up mean-variance optimization for stock portfolios. Go to yahoo finance or wherever and get some data for 100 stocks, compute the covariance matrix and there you go, a system of 100 equations from a non-madeup problem.